# SELECT with CASE WHEN and value after THEN instead of String

Tags: postgresql

My query is:

```
SELECT
    id,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(
    SELECT
        data_od
    FROM
        bp_stan_produkt
    WHERE
        id_produkt = bp_produkt.id AND data_do IS NULL AND id_stan_produkt = 313
) THEN 'TAK' ELSE 'NIE'
END AS "313"
FROM
    bp_produkt
WHERE
    id IN(21048528)
```

Is it possible to put `data_od` to column `313` instead of `TAK` or do I have to create function, make `SELECT data_od into some_variable` and `then some_variable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible:

```
select id, 
  case when exists (select data_od from bp_stan_produkt 
                  where id_produkt = bp_produkt.id and data_do is null 
                   and id_stan_produkt = 313) 
   then  (select to_char(data_od, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                   from bp_stan_produkt 
                   where id_produkt = bp.id 
                     and data_do is null
                     and id_stan_produkt = 313)
  else 'NIE'
  end as "313"
from bp_produkt 
where id in(21048528);
```

---

EDIT:

```
SELECT bp.id, COALESCE(t.data_od_t, 'NIE') AS "313"
FROM bp_produkt bp
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (select to_char(data_od, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS data_od_t 
                   from bp_stan_produkt 
                   where id_produkt = bp.id 
                     and data_do is null
                     and id_stan_produkt = 313) t 
 ON TRUE
WHERE bp.id in(21048528)
```

Comment: Thank you, works great. I accept answer as soon as it will be possible.

Comment: @Michu93 I would post better approach that avoids code duplication

Comment: That would be great